# Improving way to loop to send correct data

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to crawl multiples PDF files for data processing, however when I tried to send the num to given a query like this `https://www.google.com/search?q=filetype:PDF+%PDF-+aa&num=100&start=0`
next `&start=1` etc, but I am always having the same value 5

```
import string
ext = "pdf"
magic_header = "%PDF-"
ltrs = string.ascii_lowercase
build_query = [''.join([a,b]) for a in ltrs for b in ltrs]
max_results = 10
counter = 0
while counter < max_results:
    while True:
        if counter == 0:
            for query in build_query:
                print('https://www.google.com/search?q=filetype:{}+{}+{}&num=100&start={}'.format(ext, magic_header, query,counter))
            break
        print(counter)
        counter += 1 
    break
```

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You'll also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your use of the `while True` loop, `if counter == 0`, and the `break` statements. This should work to ensure the `counter` is always incrementing during the loop.

```py
import string

ext = "pdf"
magic_header = "%PDF-"
ltrs = string.ascii_lowercase
build_query = ["".join([a, b]) for a in ltrs for b in ltrs]
max_results = 10
counter = 0
while counter < max_results:
    for query in build_query:
        print(
            "https://www.google.com/search?q=filetype:{}+{}+{}&num=100&start={}".format(
                ext, magic_header, query, counter
            )
        )
    counter += 1
```

Edit regarding discussion below:

```py
import string

ext = "pdf"
magic_header = "%PDF-"
ltrs = string.ascii_lowercase
build_query = ["".join([a, b]) for a in ltrs for b in ltrs]
max_results = 10
counter = 0
while True:
    for query in build_query:
        print(
            "https://www.google.com/search?q=filetype:{}+{}+{}&num=100&start={}".format(
                ext, magic_header, query, counter
            )
        )

    if counter < max_results:
        break
    else:
        counter += 1
```

Comment: hw can I do it with true loop? I need the true loop

Comment: What do you need the true loop for?

Comment: If you must have a `True` loop somewhere for an assignment or something, you could just replace the `while counter < max_results:` to `while True:` and inside the loop do `if counter < max_results: break`.

Comment: I didnt get you , can you update code how? the text box doesnt allow to see code well.

Comment: Updated for ya. :)

Comment: Gentle reminder: 
If the true condition is needed for some assignment then this is NOT the right place to ask for a code. Please understand the logic and build your own code. Stackoverflow is NOT for plagiarizing work.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the loop so complicated?

Here is a simple solution. I have requested your big_query to only first 10 items in the list.

```
import string
ext = "pdf"
magic_header = "%PDF-"
ltrs = string.ascii_lowercase
build_query = [''.join([a,b]) for a in ltrs for b in ltrs][1:10]
max_results = 5
counter = 0

while counter <= max_results:
    for query in build_query:
            print('https://www.google.com/search?q=filetype:{}+{}+{}&num=100&start={}'.format(ext, magic_header,query,counter))
    counter +=1
```